# Preventing Tree label and image overlapping in Common Navigator Framework

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using Common Navigator Framework to display my tree elements. I have used SVG Icons for some tree items. It works fine for 2k monitor with 1920X1080 resolution along with 125% of text size. When I use 4k resolution monitor with 3840x2160 resolution and 250% of text size, Tree labels and icons are overlapping.

How do I solve this issue?

P.S: I'm using Windows 10 Operating system.

[image]

Comment: I think it worth mentioning some details about your platform, to get better answers. I.e. which version of Eclipse are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.


Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) and 
Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496849

Comment: @Shashwat I see that the above bug you specified is still open. Just curious that how Eclipse is working properly.

Comment: Its looks like issue is with specific resolution

Comment: Issue was with icon mismatch. I had placed png icon in parent node and svg icons for child nodes. That was causing the issue. Once I replaced parent node icon with svg, everything worked fine.